# Android Make an activity small and resize when clicked

Tags: android, android-activity

I am writing an application in which I want to make one activity small when it goes to the background and resize it when it is clicked. 
Basically I want a floating window like Skype video call floating window. 
I have tried to add an child activity for the main activity but I cannot afford to create another activity again, so my idea is to make this current activity small when go to background and resize it when it is clicked.
To make is small I do this

```
//Get the window 
Window window = getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

// Params for the window.
// You can easily set the alpha and the dim behind the window from here
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
params.alpha = 1.0f;    // lower than one makes it more transparent
params.dimAmount = 0f;  // set it higher if you want to dim behind the window
window.setAttributes(params);

// Gets the display size so that you can set the window to a percent of that
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

// You could also easily used an integer value from the shared preferences to set the percent
if (height > width) {
window.setLayout((int) (width * .35), (int) (height * .30));
} else {
window.setLayout((int) (width * .20), (int) (height * .35));
}
```

Now I want to set the onclicklistener on the window to make is bigger when clicked. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Sounds more suitable to do as a `Fragment` compared to an `Activity` to be honest. Activities are generally not meant for this since their lifecycle is vastly different to a fragment and having multiple "active" activities is not something that's feasible since version 13 (I believe it was possible before using `ActivityGroup` but I don't think it's possible now). Edit: here's the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html

Comment: How can I have a fragment without an activity. This is the map I want to show as a floating window (which is in a fragment) but how do I make this fragment's background transparent and remove the main activity from the view to allow user to do other tasks? Any idea ?